# display loading image with jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to display a spinning image while ajax call is being completed. I am using the following jsp and jquery code yet it is not working.
Any help will be appreciated 
jsp:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="rdfTabs">
            <div id="data">
                <p>Please enter dataset URL or absolute file location (e.g: c:\data\dbpedia.rdf)</p>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input name="txtDataSource" id="txtDataSource" type="text" class="textbox"/>
                        <input type="button" value="Analyse File"
                            name="btnAnalyseFile" id="btnAnalyseFile" class="btn-blue" /></td>

                    </tr>

                </table>
                **<div id="loadingImage" style="display:none">
                    <img src="http://preloaders.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif">
                </div>**
                <p id="presult">
            </div>
```

and here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#presult").hide();
            $("#btnAnalyseFile").click(
                    function(e)
                    {
                        **$("#loadingImage").show();**
                        $.ajax({
                            url : 'CreatePatternServlet',
                            type : 'POST',
                            dataType : 'json',
                            data : $("#formCreatePattern").serialize(),
                            success : function(data)
                            {   
                                if(data.analyseResult==true){
                                var predicates = {};
                                var objectList = {};
                                var ddlSubject = $('#ddlSubject');
                                var ddlPredicate = $('#ddlPredicate');
                                var ddlObject = $('#ddlObject');
                                var ddlClass = $('#ddlClass');
                                $.each(data.Subjects, function(key, value)
                                {
                                    ddlSubject.append($('<option></option>')
                                            .val(value).html(key));
                                });
                                $.each(data.Classes, function(key, value)
                                {
                                    ddlClass.append($('<option></option>')
                                            .val(value).html(key));

                                });
                                $.each(data.Predicates, function(key, value)
                                {
                                    ddlPredicate.append($('<option></option>')
                                            .val(value).html(key));
                                });
                                $.each(data.Objects, function(key, value)
                                        {

                                            ddlObject.append($('<option></option>')
                                                    .val(value).html(key));
                                        });
                                $('#ddlSubject').filterByText(
                                        $('#txtSearchSubject'));
                                $('#ddlPredicate').filterByText(
                                        $('#txtSearchPredicate'));
                                $('#ddlObject').filterByText(
                                        $('#txtSearchObject'));
                                $('#ddlClass').filterByText(
                                        $('#txtSearchClass'));

                                $("#presult").html("Data uploaded successfully");
                                $("#presult").css("color","green");
                                $("#presult").fadeIn(500);
                                }
                                else{
                                    $("#presult").html("Upload failed, please check file path or URL. Server returned error: "+data.result);
                                    $("#presult").css("color","red");
                                    $("#presult").fadeIn(500);
                                }

                            }
                        });
                        **$('#loadingImage').hide();**
                        return false;
                    });
        });
```

Comment: $('#loadingImage').hide(); should go inside success or on a done function, if not id fires inmediately as ajax is async

Comment: ok but it doesn't show at all.
I will put it inside the success function

Comment: ok it started working after your suggestion. can you write it as an answer so I mark it for people who look for it afterwards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your ajax function is asynchronous, so you are showing the loader, firing the ajax and inmediately hiding the loader, without waiting for the request to end.

Easy fix is putting the  `$('#loadingImage').hide();` inside the success function, but would be better to add a done function in case it fails

Comment: this should be the correct answer; first comment the hide() function to see if it does show up, if it does, move the hide function to the top of the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnAnalyseFile").click(function() etc...
```

shoudn't be

```
$("#btnAnalyseFile").on("click", function() { etc...
```

?

Comment: actually the rest of the code works except for showing the image